# how to connect a c program to mysql

Tags: mysql, c

I am just learning mysql . here I have written very simple program in c . I need to connect it to mysql database. I mean to say output  has  to store in mysql database . how can I do it. I referred mysql tutorial but I couldn't get the answer. so thought will start implementing with a simple program. please somebody guide me. Thank you

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main( ) 
{ 
int num1, num2, sum; 
printf("Enter a two integers: "); 
scanf("%d %d",&num1,&num2); num1=num1+num2; 
printf("Sum: %d",num1); 
return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are many examples available on the Internet. Use your favorite search engine to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a copy-paste (more or less) from a program I wrote a while ago that connects to MySQL using their C API:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <my_global.h>
#include <mysql.h>

typedef struct
{
    char host[20];
    char user[25];
    char pass[50];
}DB_CONN_PARAMS;

MYSQL * connect_db(DB_CONN_PARAMS *params)
{
    MYSQL *connection = mysql_init(NULL);//init connection
    if (connection == NULL)
    {//check init worked
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(connection));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE):
    }
    //connect:
    if (mysql_real_connect(
            connection,
            params->host,
            params->user,
            params->pass,
            NULL,0,NULL,0)
        ==NULL)
    {//connection failed?
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(connection));
        mysql_close(connection);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE):
    }
    return connection;
}

int main()
{
    MYSQL *db;
    DB_CONN_PARAMS *params = calloc(1,sizeof(DB_CONN_PARAMS));
    //just an alternative way of passing connection params, find a struct easier
    params->host = "127.0.0.1";
    params->user = "root";
    params->pass = "mySuperSecretPass";
    MYSQL * connect_db(DB_CONN_PARAMS *params);
    db = connect_db(params);
    //we don't need the struct anymore
    free(params);
    params = NULL;
    //do stuff
    mysql_close(db);//close connection, of course!
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I've taken most of my inspiration from [the code samples on the MySQL website](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-stmt-execute.html). They do work, honest.
When compiling, you do have to keep a few things in mind. The code above should compile just fine using gcc like so:

```
gcc yourCode.c -std=c99 `mysql_config --cflags --libs` -o yourBin
```

When it comes to executing queries, as you want to do, I suggest you bookmark [The C-API documentation on mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/c-api.html).
Without using prepared statements, your code might end up looking something like:

```
int main()
{
    MYSQL *db;
    char query_str[150];//query string here
    int num1, num2, q_status;//your ints, + 1 to check success of query
    DB_CONN_PARAMS *params = calloc(1,sizeof(DB_CONN_PARAMS));
    params->host = "127.0.0.1";
    params->user = "root";
    params->pass = "mySuperSecretPass";
    MYSQL * connect_db(DB_CONN_PARAMS *params);
    db = connect_db(params);
    free(params);
    //get numbers
    scanf("%d %d", num1, num2);
    //insert num1, num2 and sum into query string
    sprintf(query_str,
            "INSERT INTO your_db.table (num1, num2, sum) VALUES (%d,%d,%d);",
            num1,num2,(num1 + num2)
    );
    //run our query
    q_status = mysql_query(db, query_str);
    if (q_status)
    {//insert failed
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to execute \"%s\"\n%s\n", query_str, mysql_error(db));
        mysql_close(db);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    //YaY, it worked!
    printf("Insert successful:\nQuery used: \"%s\"\n", query_str);
    mysql_close(db);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

But that's leaving out resultsets, prepared statements, and all other things that will be useful in a real-life program. Please, do browse through the documentation I've linked to in my answer, it's not hard to grasp, it's just a bit of a faff at times, the MySQL C API...

Comment: thank you sir. i will go through the links.i have a doubt reagrding the database , like do i need to create a database before running this c program?

Comment: @shishira: If all you're going to do is insert into a specific table, then you'll probably be easier off creating that beforehand. If your program is going to be deployed on various machines, you might include a check and create function, too. There are examples of how this can be done on de mysql docs pages (multiple statements using `mysql_real_query` I think...)

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <mysql.h>
#include <stdio.h>
main() {
   MYSQL *conn;
   MYSQL_RES *res;
   MYSQL_ROW row;
   char *server = "localhost";
   char *user = "root";
   char *password = "PASSWORD"; /* set me first */
   char *database = "mysql";
   conn = mysql_init(NULL);
   /* Connect to database */
   if (!mysql_real_connect(conn, server,
         user, password, database, 0, NULL, 0)) {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
      exit(1);
   }
   /* send SQL query */
   if (mysql_query(conn, "show tables")) {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
      exit(1);
   }
   res = mysql_use_result(conn);
   /* output table name */
   printf("MySQL Tables in mysql database:\n");
   while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) != NULL)
      printf("%s \n", row[0]);
   /* close connection */
   mysql_free_result(res);
   mysql_close(conn);
}
```

for detailed explanation read here http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-unix-connect-mysql-c-api-program.html

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/

Comment: do i need to create a database table separately in order to store ma results in that? i know m asking a silly question but i want to clear my doubt sir.

Comment: @shishira ya u need to create a database. char *database = "mysql" in this code we are just declaring your database not creating it.so it should be present.

Comment: but by default in mysql the database with name mysql will already be there.just look for it,u will find it.

Comment: ok.i used following code to create a table.  create table add_tbl( sum int NOT NULL ); the thing my c program will perform add operation and store it in database. will this code be sufficient to fetch the result?

Comment: @shishira in your case you are performing an add operation so that will return the sum of the numbers you are adding so table with 1 column is enough for holding the value.

Comment: @shishira i hope your all doubts are clear,agar fir bhi koi doubt ho toh please do ask.

Comment: thanks a lot.. but its not cleared yet :)  i need to work on mysql a lott

Comment: My c program isn't storing the result in the database! i dont know why

Comment: @shishira what error you are getting?

Comment: like incompatible type errors :(